# Apache redirect .js request to PHP request

Tags: php, javascript, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to serve a JavaScript response from a JavaScript request using PHP.

Assuming that the request is embedded into the HTML source as

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://www.mydomain.com/generatejs.js\" charset=\"UTF-8\"></script>
```

And i have a PHP script that is called generatejs.js.php which outputs more JavaScript code

The Apache rewrite condition/rule are

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But I am getting a 404 when trying to access http://www.mydomain.com/generatejs.js. Can someone please help me with the missing bit? :)

Comment: You could just reference the PHP file directly.  <script src="file.php"> style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RewriteRule` is not matching `/generatejs.js` because of the `[^\.]+` (which is anything BUT a `.`) So, if you update it to the following, you should have better luck:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.js$ $1.js.php [NC,L]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^generatejs.js$ generatejs.js.php
```

Comment: Thanks, i took the general solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.js$ $1.js.php [NC,L]
```

Now every smth.js file is redirected to smth.js.php